# ul li menu dropdown not display in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using ul li menu drop down for my site.. it displayed in ifrefox and chrome correctly. but in IE its not displayed... 
my code like..,

```
<style type="text/css"> .nav { width:1000px; } .nav ul { }
.nav ul li  { list-style: none;}
ul.dropdown { position:relative; width:auto; font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
ul.dropdown li { float:left; zoom:1; height:30px; padding:6px 2px 0 2px; border-right:1px solid #bacfe4; }
ul.dropdown li li { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;  margin-left:9px;}
ul.dropdown a:hover { color:#000; } ul.dropdown a:active { color:#ffa500; }
ul.dropdown li a { display:block; padding:4px 8px; color:#000; text-decoration:none; font:bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a { border-right:none;}
ul.dropdown li:hover { color:#000; position:relative; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a { color:#000; }
ul.dropdown ul { text-align:left; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left:-10px; top:36px; }
ul.dropdown ul li { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; float:none; width:120px; height:25px; }
ul.dropdown ul li a { border-right:none; width:100%; display:inline-block; color:#000; }
ul.dropdown ul ul { left:100%; top:0; }
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul { visibility:visible; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<div class="nav">

<ul class='dropdown'>
<li><a href=''>one</a></li>
<li><a href=''>two</a></li>
<li> <a href=''> three </a>
<ul class='sub_menu'>
<li><a href=''>one3</a></li>
<li><a href=''>two3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have not specified DOCTYPE. Have you specified?? if not then specify it  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: don't used .nav used .navi because nav is a tag for html 5

Comment: its not displaying when i changed that .nav to .navi... i included the DOCTYPE also.. nothing works....

Answer (score 0):

I included the jquery.js file two times in my actual page.

Thats why it was not displaying.